# Bulk Inserting data into SQL Server Table without locking

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, locking, bulkinsert

Is there any way that we could do a bulk insert into a table without causing any kind of table or block level locks? If not what size blocks needs to be processed in order to avoid locking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use a dynamic sql and update/insert using batch of 1000 or 10000 based on the data volume, index, key column and constrains.

A sample dynamic sql.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDetails] 
(
@l_value NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@l_name NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE Table1 SET Value = [' + @l_value + '] WHERE Name =['+ @l_name + '] '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END
```